# Ankh Subversion Force Checkin of Older Revision

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I'd like to update all files of a project to an older revision and I'm having a bit of trouble. I was able to pull the older revisions down but I don't know how to turn them into the current revision. I've seen answers on how to do this through the command line but I'm curious if it's possible in Ankh. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the history viewer, right-click on the revision you want to return to, and choose "Revert to this revision". Alternatively, pick the revision(s) you want to undo (you can multi-select them) and choose "Revert changes from this/these revisions"